# Angular: Where would this constructor be placed?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-services

I found a very useful tutorial on creating an angular factory that takes parameters.  However useful, there's a hiccup.

Below, the factory creates an instance of a function-object/constructor.  The author of the tutorial does not explain where the this "Inventory" constructor should be placed.

**Would the "Inventory" constructor go into a separate file, say as an module/IFFE?**

```
/*  WHERE DOES THIS INVENTORY OBJECT GO?? */
function Inventory($http, url, project_id) {
 /** The public method for getting the project price **/
 this.price = function(callback) {
      $http.get(url+"?project="+project_id)
            .success(function(value) {
               callback(value);
            });
   };
};

angular.factory('InventoryFactory',[
 '$http',
   /** This is the factory method that Angular will execute only ONCE **/
   function InventoryFactory($http) {
   /** This is the function that will be injected into the directive, and called multiple times by the programmer **/
   return function(url, product_id) {
       /** this is the new object that will be created and used by the programmer **/
       return new Inventory($http, url, product_id);
    };
 }]);

angular.directive('inventoryStatus',['InventoryFactory',function(InventoryFactory) {
 return {
    link: function($scope,$el,$attr) {
         var inventory =  InventoryFactory('/api/projects',$scope.project_id);
         inventory.price(function(value){
            $scope.price = value;
         });
      }
   }
}]);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Link to the tutorial: https://www.thinkingmedia.ca/2015/01/how-to-create-a-factory-in-angularjs-that-takes-parameters/

Comment: Does it matter where it goes? This is just a class if you have it in a Inventory.js and you will load it. It will be placed on the Window object i think. Same here in this code you can place an IFFE around it

Comment: "Does it matter where it goes?" is exactly what I'm asking.  I have factory, directive and controller in separate files. 1) So, given that and that the Inventory constructor/class takes $http and if in separate file, it needs to be wrapped in an Angular module, right? 2) If so, what would such an Angular module be classified as? 3) Given Inventory is performing the XHR, however, would it be best practice to keep it in the factory?

Comment: It has only to do with loading your javascript files. You need to make sure that Inventory function is available when you want to use it. the $http is just a variable. that will be filled when you call the Factory with your parameters. So there are a couple of things: 1) Make sure that all the objects / functions are visible to eachother and 2) make sure they are loaded in the correct order.

Comment: I see.  Will give it a shot.  Thank you, Jordy.